# Soul package and input encoding

Tags: input-encodings, soul

I have the following code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[english,greek]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{kerkis}

\usepackage{color,soul}

\setul{0.1cm}{0.2ex}
\setulcolor{red}


\begin{document}

%\ul{Τεστ}
\ul{Test}
\textlatin{\ul{Test}}

\end{document}
```

which produces:

[image]

However, if I uncomment the line `%\ul{Τεστ}`, there are many errors produced, without getting any output. I guess this issue has to do with the encoding. How am I to override it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Greek letters need some more work for soul due to the utf8 encoding -- there is `soulutf8` as an extension of `soul` for this (and other non latin characters)

There is no need to load `soul` separately.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english,greek]{babel}
\usepackage{soulutf8}
\usepackage{kerkis}

\usepackage{xcolor}

\setul{0.1cm}{0.2ex}
\setulcolor{red}


\begin{document}

\protect\ul{Τεστ}
\ul{Test}
\textlatin{\ul{Test}}

\end{document}
```

[image]