# Inputencoding and twemojis

Tags: packages, input-encodings

The `twemojis` package does not seem to get along with `[applemac]{inputenc}`.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage[applemac]{inputenc}
\usepackage{twemojis}
\begin{document}
\end{document}
```

Error message:

```
Missing $ insert
ed.
<inserted text> 
                $
l.143 ...{1f1e6-1f1fd}{flag: ^^c3^^85land Islands}
```

If I uncomment either line 2 or line 3, the file compiles without problems. Is there a way for me to use both packages?

(I've noticed that `twemojis` can cause other problems, as reported [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/601530/twemojis-package-cant-be-used-doesnt-show-up-locally-and-cant-be-installed), and that `{applemac}[inputenc]` can have issues with other packages, like [this one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/254823/soul-package-and-input-encoding) but I do not seem able to find advice on this particular problem.)

Comment: Is your editor really still saving files in the legacy Apple encoding? In 2022, I find that hard to believe …

Answer (score 0):

Apologies but I realised only now that it works if I load `twemojis` before `[applemac]{inputenc}`. Not sure why but this solved my problem.

This works for me:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{twemojis}
\usepackage[applemac]{inputenc}
\begin{document}
\end{document}
```

Comment: well, nowadays hardly any normal document should be using anything but `utf8` encoding. `applemac`, `latin1` and `ansinew` should be left for legacy documents.

Comment: `utf8` does not play well with my bibliography

Comment: Then convert your bibliography to something more modern. The TeXStudio editor can change the encoding of a file. Besides it also very much depends on how you make your bibliography. If you're using `bibtex` then the bibliography should strictly speaking be written in ascii, aka no special letter, they all need to the written using LaTeX macros.

Comment: @NCH32 then better correct your bibliography. Your files will be much more portable if you use utf8 everywhere.

Comment: Yes, we had this conversation over here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/604788/texshop-loses-umlauts-in-tex-files

Comment: @daleif: Thanks for this pointer: "the bibliography should strictly speaking be written in ascii, aka no special letter, they all need to the written using LaTeX macros." Is there a fool-proof way to do this? I tried re-encoding the `bib` file in utf8 but it is ten or fifteen years old, quite long, and I have so far not succeeded creating a version that would work well with all my other files.

Comment: For such a file you might have a mixture of encodings in the same file and then it can be very very hard to convert. I'd probably use tools that can identify non ascii letters and then replace by hand. Doing it automatically is sadly error prone.